# Installing dev dependencies in Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, webpack, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my React app to the Google Cloud App Engine. I've added a `app.yaml` file too. It Looks like this:

```
// app.yaml    
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Now, I want to build my project using webpack before deployment. So following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime), I've added `prestart` script to the `package.json`. Now my scripts portion of package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm-run-all --parallel webpack-client-build webpack-server-build",
    "webpack-server-build": "NODE_ENV='development' webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors --watch",
    "webpack-client-build": "NODE_ENV='development' webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.browser.config.js --progress --colors --watch",
    "build-prod": "npm-run-all webpack-client-build-prod webpack-server-build-prod",
    "webpack-server-build-prod": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.server.config.js -p",
    "webpack-client-build-prod": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.browser.config.js -p",
    "prestart": "npm run build-prod",
    "start": "pm2 start dist/main.js"
  },
```

I'm using `npm-run-all` to build both server side and client side pacakges. But because of this, my build is failing as in docs it says

```
Note: Webpack must be listed in the dependencies of the package.json file, as by default devDependencies are not installed when the app is deployed to Google App Engine.
```

How can I install the node dev dependencies for deployment of my Node app in the Google Cloud ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

When Google Cloud spins up an app it runs `npm install` however it only has access to `dependencies` and not `devDependencies`.

Try moving `webpack` into the `dependencies` portion of `package.json`.

Comment: This does not solve the issue of if we need devDependencies to be installed in app engine

Comment: @FaultyJuggler why would you need devDependencies installed on the app engine? That should be for development purposes. App Engine deployments are when you are pushing something up to staging/production type environments?

Also, I'm not telling how to add it. I specifically mentioned that GCP doesn't have access to those.

Comment: a particular open source project I'm running will only run if it's own modules are listed under devDepencies as their production mode actually is starting with "npm run dev" - I don't agree with their choice, but their decision is that any additional modules you want, go under dependencies, while their core modules remain under devDependencies as a separation.  It's not something I can change, so I'm asking how to get App Engine to include devDependencies.  Others have got it running by creating a docker image and then building on top of that rather than app deploy as I'm trying to do.

Comment: Gotcha, unfortunately I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of GCP, I used it for a project a couple years ago which is when I answered this question. I haven't touched it since :/ -- Your comment about docker makes sense and I would suggest chasing that down

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help